# Python 3.10.2, Pygame "AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'image'

Tags: python, image, pygame, attributes

I'm new to programming and just following the steps provided online to make a small game in pygame to learn.

I have run into a problem.

Here is my code

```
#sprite
import pygame

FPS=60
WHITE=(255,255,255)
GREEN=(0,255,0)
WIDTH=500
HEIGHT=600

#遊戲初始化 and 創建視窗
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("spacegame")
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite._init_(self)
        self.image =pygame.Surface((50,40))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x =200
        self.rect.y =200

all_sprites= pygame.sprite.Group()
player=Player()
all_sprites.add(player)


#遊戲迴圈
running=True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    #取得輸入
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
    #更新遊戲
    all_sprites.update()

    #畫面顯示
    
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.display.update()
    
pygame.quit()
```

And I got the output:

```
AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'image'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I got the steps from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61eX0bFAsYs&t=1367s

Answer (score 0):

In your player class you've called the **init** method incorrectly. you've written

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite._init_(self)
```

there should be **two** underscores next to "init" not just one. what you should be writing is:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
```

also sorry to butt in but your player sprite won't actually display on the screen with this code. you'd have to put the `screen.fill(white)` *before* the `all_sprites.draw(screen)` or else you'll add the white on top of your green box and won't be able to see it.

I recommend checking out some videos about classes and OOP in python to understand why the `__init__`method is like that and how it works.